# Cannot import name 'MappingProxyType' error after importing functools

Tags: python, import, functools

After I import functools I receive such message from interpreter:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python/decorator.py", line 1, in 
>       import functools
>     File "C:\Python3\lib\functools.py", line 22, in 
>       from types import MappingProxyType
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'

```
import functools


def trace(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__name__, args, kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    functools.update_wrapper(inner, func)
    return inner


@trace
def foo(x):
    return x


foo(42)
```

Using PyCharm as IDE and CPython as interpreter

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is not a real answer, but a comment.

First: I can't verify the problem presented: The code within the question works perfectly in the standard python I am using.

Second: I stumbled upon this question because I had the same error message, but maybe for a different reason. I accidentally named a module "type". Strangely the python framework selected this new "type" module while resolving references from within imported system modules. Which indicates that python's algorithm of resolving references is a bit ... well ... of a bit of very simple design.

Nevertheless if readers get this error message please check first if you accidentally named something "type" somewhere in your code as a first approach to solve the problem before checking other reasons for that error message.

***Update:*** This is a quite common phenomenon in Python. Be careful! Whenever you give your module a name that has already been used for any imported Python module (and you might not be aware of these names!) you will have the chance of getting strange errors more or less similar to the one described in the question.

Comment: It worked!! I named a module `types.py` and this error showed up. After renaming it everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Prashanth I've also named a module `types.py` and it really interfered with the import procedure. Since this is not mentioned in the numpy error message, consider changing your comment to a full answer, to highlighting it to future developers with the same problem. (just a suggestion though) :-)

Comment: Hero! I had a module named types as well. never thought of that to be the cause. thanks! @Regis May

Comment: for my case i had named a folder `types` and after renaming it it worked perfectly

Comment: In my case these files/directories are generated with a tool `protoc` and is really difficult to change. Any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution forces you to rename your module, but:

There's nothing wrong with having a module named `types` in your package, actually you'll get this error if the interpreter is run with either the current directory or a `PYTHONPATH` directory is set to the directory containing the module.

If you avoid this situation, you won't have to rename your module.

If you use an IDE, check the run configuration to make sure `PYTHONPATH` or current directory isn't set to include your modules.

Comment: I was using no IDE.

Comment: On Pycharm I have unchecked "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" and it is all good. Thanks!

Comment: @Eduardo after your suggestion, the error message now changed to `ImportError: cannot import name 'GenericAlias' from 'types' (/Users/xxx/xxx/types/__init__.py`. Any suggestions please?