# ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType' from 'types'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-wheel

I see this question has been asked several time but in most cases there is just one resolution which is to change the module or class name from type to something else.

For my case, this entire directory/file structure is generated using `protoc` and it is possible for me change anything at source code level.

I cannot change the structure of my protobuf messages which to allow renaming from `type` to something else.

My end goal is to be able to generate a wheel package out of my python directory (which has subdirectory to many levels) and allow including module with name `type` in it.

The error message I am getting when running `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType' from 'types' (/Users/shashwat/xxx/myproject/types/__init__.py)`

I tried [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453414/cannot-import-name-mappingproxytype-error-after-importing-functools#comment117150537_59860454) from PyCharm but then the error message changes to:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'GenericAlias' from 'types' (/Users/shashwat/xxx/myproject/types/__init__.py)`

Please let me know in case of more information is required.